# Drupal 8 Views Question Involving Entity Reference

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

Trying to figure out views relationships and filters.

I'm trying to make a view that has the title of the page match the entity reference of the same page and make it reactive so I only need one. EX.) Page about animals, which there are nodes referencing the animal page as an entity reference.

Comment: A better example: If I'm a page, i want the view to filter by the page by grabbing all the nodes that have an entity reference to the current page im on.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have to take one unique field which can identify whether particular node is for animals or etc.

After that, In your views you need to select that field name in contextual filter and select option as you can see in screenshot and then save it.

[image]